# How to search for a 'string' within 'any file' that is within the directory of /usr/test/ only

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

My operating system is : Centos Desktop.
I would like to search for a text string

within any file that is within the directory of

```
  /usr/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

try grep string -r /usr/test

will search /usr/test and all subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

use grep

you can take a look at the documentation of grep

for a simple example look at

https://superuser.com/questions/268190/how-to-grep-or-find-exactly-what-i-am-looking-for

Answer (score 0):

**grep "your text" -r /usr/test**

or **cd** to **/usr/test** then "**grep "your text"  *.fileExtension**"

Answer (score 0):

Simply grep the directory with your string

## grep "YOUR_TEXT_STRING" /usr/test

Answer (score 0):

grep 'regex' -r /usr/test
try it